# What to do after adding sitemap.xml to the main folder in xampp?

Tags: php, xml, xampp, sitemap

I created sitemap online and I downloaded the sitemap.xml and added it to the main folder for the site in xampp. I get this error: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below".

Comment: That's fine and normal since it doesn't have any visual elements. You're done.

Comment: The question is a bit strange: you did something, then ask us what to do afterwards, but you don't mention with a single word _why_ you did something of _what_ you want to achieve... So one possible answer to your question is: go and have a coffee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how browsers are going to display a sitemap.xml file.

If you can see it, when visiting the URL, it is working.

As noted by John and arkascha you are done, go have a coffee! ;)

**EDIT:**

If you would like to display a 'site map', as a human readable page, you would simply create a new page on your website(like any other standard content page).

Then add your list of pages, And the links to those pages, to your site map page.

In other words websites that have a human readable page do not use the XML file, but instead they create a standard page with links.

Comment: I want to display it maybe something like this: [link](http://www.toshiba.com/tai/site_map.jsp), but what I have is code written like this: <url>
<loc>localhost/bis/home.php</loc>
<priority>1.0</priority>
<lastmod>2007-10-05</lastmod>
<changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
</url>.

Comment: @MohamedNader I have updated my answer, please see the EDIT.

Comment: got u. Thanks for ceasing the confusion! :D

Comment: @MohamedNader If this solved your question please mark it as such, thank you.